# Can't Run Aimsun examples in FLOW

Tags: python, docker, flow-project

I followed the installation tutorial and installed [FLOW](https://github.com/flow-project/flow) both locally and through Docker. In both cases, the SUMO examples worked but the Aimsun examples didn't run.

1. On my local Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I have installed FLOW and SUMO, and was able to run the SUMO example flow/examples/sumo/sugiyama.py. Then I followed the installation tutorial and download/installed Aimsun 8.4.0 and Aimsun 8.3.1 in default install paths (/home/Aimsun_Next_8_4_0 and /home/Aimsun_Next_8_3_1).
2. But during the next step, I was asked to run the script `scripts/setup_aimsun.sh` however the code didn't execute because `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - python=2.7.4`. I then used `conda search python` to see what versions of python does Anaconda have in store. It turned out that only versions from `python                        2.7.13     hac47a24_15  pkgs/main` to `python                         3.7.4      h265db76_1  pkgs/main` are available. So I gave in and changed the script from `python=2.7.4` to `python=2.7` and ran the script `scripts/setup_aimsun.sh` again. This time the installation went through, and python 2.7.16 was installed instead of 2.7.4. And the output of `activate aimsun_flow` and `which python` produced `/home/tong/anaconda3/envs/aimsun_flow/bin/python`, which is expected.
3. Then I edited the file /flow/config.py to include the newly created paths:
   `AIMSUN_NEXT_PATH = "/home/tong/Aimsun_Next_8_3_1/"
   AIMSUN_SITEPACKAGES = "/home/tong/anaconda3/envs/aimsun_flow/"`
4. Next I tried to test the Aimsun example using commands: `conda activate flow` and 'python examples/aimsun/sugiyama.py 
   ', this is the error message I got:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "examples/aimsun/sugiyama.py", line 59, in <module>
        exp = sugiyama_example()
      File "examples/aimsun/sugiyama.py", line 52, in sugiyama_example
        env = TestEnv(env_params, sim_params, scenario, simulator='aimsun')
      File "/home/tong/github/flow/flow/envs/base_env.py", line 150, in __init__
        self.k.scenario.generate_network(scenario)
      File "/home/tong/github/flow/flow/core/kernel/scenario/aimsun.py", line 122, in generate_network
        self.aimsun_proc = subprocess.Popen(aimsun_call)
      File "/home/tong/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 729, in __init__
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "/home/tong/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
        raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
    OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/home/tong/Aimsun_Next_8_3_1/Aimsun_Next'`

5. On the Docker container version, Aimsun is not pre-installed, so the Aimsun example couldn't be run either (check the link for image):
   [aimsun_error](https://flic.kr/p/2h4PsbQ)

Not sure why Aimsun couldn't be run in both cases. Could it be because I don't have the exact version of python 2.7.4 in the conda environment?

Comment: Aimsun is a niche application, you'll need to provide much more explanation including links to the tutorial you refer to and evidence of what you've tried before people can help. I'd suggest tagging this with aimsun too.

Comment: I am not completely sure, but this error could be mostly due to the path that is set by the flow. Can you run `echo $PATH` and report what you see?

Comment: As mentioned in the installation instructions of Flow, you need to set the variable `AIMSUN_NEXT_PATH` in the `flow/config.py` file to the path where Aimsun is installed on your computer.

Comment: @Ashkan I tried and this is the output:

/home/tong/github/sumo/bin:/home/tong/sumo_binaries/bin:/home/tong/anaconda3/condabin:/home/tong/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Comment: @nathanlct Yes, I think I did that, and here's the change I made to flow/config.py

    # path to the Aimsun_Next main directory (required for Aimsun simulations)
    AIMSUN_NEXT_PATH = "/home/tong/Aimsun_Next_8_3_1/"

    # path to the aimsun_flow environment's main directory (required for Aimsun
    # simulations)
    AIMSUN_SITEPACKAGES = "/home/tong/anaconda3/envs/aimsun_flow/"

Comment: __Exec format error__ means that you're using a compiled binary in the wrong operating system. Lookup the write binary for your Debian machine.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thank you, may I ask how to look up the write binary? I'm not familiar with it and don't know how to search on google. My OS is Ubuntu 18.04, which I installed myself on my laptop from the official Ubuntu website.